# How to move to new line in mvc5 on server side

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5.1

I use the many tag like /n and 
 but all are not work.please suggest me the best approch for it

```
 string shamus = "access" + "<br><br>"+"good";


string shamus = "access" + "<br/>"+"good";
 string shamus = "access" + "\n"+"good";
```

Comment: How do you render that string shamus to view?

Comment: i call it on button click i want only to move new line the work good

Comment: you need to show the view where you are rendering the string